# Removing controls on a Javascript page and placing in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to implement highcharts into my application.

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.6/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick/

**I want to remove the zoom controls (like 1m, 3m, 6m, YTD, 1y, All) from the chart and place them out of the container div. But i don't want those controls inside the chart. I want to place those controls at the top of the page.**

```
Please can any one help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it is possible to do what you are looking.  You will simply need to make use of the built-in functions of the API as one of the developers mentioned here:

[http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10915&p=49390&hilit=external+controls#p49463](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10915&p=49390&hilit=external%20controls#p49463)

Basically you make a chart w/out the actual controls and then create the necessary code to manipulate the content of the chart accordingly.